# Seeking clarification on the idea of contacting a moderator via chat on a different stack site

Tags: discussion, bug, chat, rules

Right now, my post is on hold. I have taken in consideration of the improvement on the post. Since, I am unable to make contact with moderators who put the question on hold. Perhaps, I'm being impatient can I still ask and not break the rules?

*I was wondering if it is permissible to ask the same moderators but on different stack-exchange sites via chat?*

I also can't use meta for cs-theory

[image]

Here is step two.

[image]

Comment: I assume you're referring to [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/43817/language-shiftl-seems-to-be-co-np-complete-in-n2-x-n2-sudoku-generation). Those are just regular users who put your question on hold; not elected moderators. You just edited it an hour ago. Give it some time. By editing the post it has put it in the reopen queue where it will be reviewed to see if it should be reopened. This isn't going to happen at the snap of a finger.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you post about your question on Theoretical CS Meta, like I advised you on your prior deleted post?

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog I tried that and it still says need 5 rep.

Comment: When you visit https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/ and click "Ask Question", are you not given the option to "ask a question about your own post specifically" and given a field to paste a link to your question? You should be, otherwise it's a bug.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog I am given the option, but then it still don't work.

Comment: You *should* be able to post your question on meta, but if worse comes to worse and you can't find a solution soon, just suggest 2 good edits on the main site and you'll be at 5 reputation.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog I redid it and the text pops in there by itself like this. I have a question about my Theoretical Computer Science Stack Exchange post: Language shift(L) seems to be co-np complete in n^2 x n^2 Sudoku Generation

Comment: Yeah, you have to keep that text there. From your screenshot, it looks like you're deleting that text, and therefore the system is blocking your post. Try that and see if it works.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog I did not remove or edit it and still problem. I added text above the "do not delete'

Comment: Try putting it *below* that text instead of above; the system might just be checking for it at the top.

Comment: Some helpful tips: You've made 20+ edits to that question, that won't be popular, you should write up your question in a text editor (at home) and read it over before submitting it. I do my editing on-site and just leave the window open, submitting it when I've triple checked it; then I quickly read it once it's submitted to see if it needs a tweak (**under** the **5** minute window) -- Sometimes a particular site is not *for* a particular person, you seem to be doing OK on the other sites; so make hay where the Sun shines. In any event, now you wait patiently. Don't get discouraged. GL

Comment: By the way, I filed a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327702/make-error-message-if-a-new-user-removes-or-misplaces-the-mandatory-header-text) asking for that error message to be changed, to avoid the confusion that happened here with you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should *not* be specifically contacting someone because they put your question on hold. There's already a required close reason stating why the question is not a good fit for the site, and moderators tend to leave comments on posts that they close.

Before you do anything, please check your site's [on-topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [off-topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) guides. There are often cases where you *think* your question is on-topic for a site, but it's actually not.

If there's any way you can improve your question by editing, please do so. Edits made within 5 days of closure send a post to review where privileged users can review it and decide if it should be reopened or not.

Additionally, you can ask on the site's [per-site meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) if you believe your question was wrongly closed. This allows you to receive more feedback and exposes it to more users across the site.

Comment: Need 5 rep. Even tried what sonic did and it won't work

Comment: @TravisWells when asking a question on meta with <5 rep, you should have the option to ask about one of your questions on the main site. You may have to navigate directly to `site.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask` to ask your question, but it should work.